# Trying to prove whether $\lim_\limits{z \to 0} e^{-1/z^4}$ exists or not.

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, limits, inequality, complex-numbers

This problem involves complex analysis, and the limit is as follows:

> $\lim_\limits{z \to 0} e^{-1/z^4}$

I have to either show that this limit exists, or that it does not.

This is how I've approached this problem:

> $\lim_\limits{x \to 0} e^{-1/x^4}$ = 0
>
> $\lim_\limits{y \to 0} e^{-1/(yi)^4}$ = 0

With that, I've come to the following hypothesis:

> $\lim_\limits{z \to 0} e^{-1/z^4}$ = 0

And now I've tried to prove this hypothesis like so:

> With $\epsilon>0$,
>
> $|e^{-1/z^4} - 0| < \epsilon$ whenever $0 < |z - 0| < \delta$
>
> = $|e^{-1/z^4}| < \epsilon$ whenever $0 < |z| < \delta$

However, I can't get any further than this step.. Please help me with this final part, I only have until tomorrow morning to prove this!

Comment: Hint: Write $z=re^{i\theta}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about looking at the limit of $e^{-1/z_n^4}$ along the sequence $(z_n)_n$ defined by
$$
z_n = \frac{1}{n}e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}
$$
and also along the other sequence
$$
z_n = \frac{1}{n}
$$
?

Comment: Hmm.. I would like to try this, but am not sure how. Would you mind giving me an example? Or pointing me to a reference that uses this approach?

Comment: If the limit exists, it has to be the same along all complex sequences that converge to $0$ (and never cancel). These are two different sequences that converge to $0$; if the limit is not the same, then it shows the overall limit cannot exist.

Comment: I voted both answers up, but yours proved to be easier to show

Answer (score 3):

Hint: try evaluating

$$\lim_{t \to 0} e^{-1/((1+i)t)^4}$$

Comment: I'm probably missing something, but how would I relate this to my proof?

Comment: It is a counterexample: the limit above will not be $0$.

Comment: @ClementC. I think I understand what you're saying. Just so I'm sure I understand: I can put any complex value that tends to 0 in the place of z and show that if the limit no longer tends to 0, it dne?

Comment: @ClementC. This complex analysis stuff makes my head spin.. Sorry if I seem like I'm not even trying, I'm fairly new to this stuff!

Comment: No worries. That trick not only for complex analysis: to show that the limit of a function $f$ at $a$ does not exist, it's sufficient to find two sequences $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$, both converging to $a$, such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(a_n)\neq \lim_{n\to\infty}f(b_n)$. (Indeed, if $f$ *had* a limit $\lambda$ at $a$, then all such sequences would have to satisfy $f(a_n)\to\lambda$ and $f(b_n)\to\lambda$)